# Opening two ports

Tags: ports

I have 2 ip cameras, one is operating on port 8021 the other I would like to operate on 8022
I have successfully opened a port forwarding rule for port 8021 and can see my camera output from outside my network
I also have a rule set up for port 8022 but using port checker I see it is closed.
What could be stopping this port from opening?

Comment: [The same question here](http://superuser.com/q/1096119/432690), no answers yet.

Comment: Can you get to the second camera from inside the network?  What URL do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Some possibilities -

- The camera does not have a default gateway ?
- The camera is operating on a different port, eg 8021 ?
- There is a firewall blocking port 8022 ?
- There is confusion due to NAT ?

If your router has the ability to dump packets, look at whats traversing which interface.   If not, try substituting a PC with a similar server on port 8021 and doing a traffic dump on that - this could help work out if its a device problem or routing issue.